# Make the whole process last a set time

Tags: javascript

I'm creating a script to change letters in a button a-la "TV - cracking a password" style, random letters, slowly getting figured out on by one.

I want it to run for the same amount of time (2 seconds), regardless of the final string length. So `ABC`, and `This is a longer string!`, would both take 2 seconds, but with `ABC`, each letter is randomised more times.

The variables I have I know so far are, it will run for 2000 milliseconds, every 50 milliseconds, and I know the output text length, e.g. 3 and 24. I need to know how many times each letter will get changed.

I've been racking my brain trying to get it to work, to no avail.

[Here's a link to a live demo](https://jsfiddle.net/tomharto/nw8sa8ry/)

```
<input type="text" id="text" />
<input type="button" id="change" value="Change" />
<br /><br />
<span id="output">This is where the output will</span>
```

```
$(function(){

    var chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');
    function getRandomInt(min, max){
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
    }

    function randomChar(){
        return chars[getRandomInt(0, chars.length - 1)];
    }

    var $output = $('#output');
    $output.text($output.text() + ' be');


    var INTERVAL = 50;

    var newOutput = function($elem, $newText){

        var chars = new String($newText).split('');
        var totalChars = chars.length;
        var doneChars = 0;


        var timer = setInterval(function(){

            var output = '';
            for(var staticChars = 0;staticChars < doneChars;staticChars++){
                output += chars[staticChars];
            }

            for(var randomChars = 0;randomChars < (totalChars -    doneChars);randomChars++){
                output += randomChar();
            }

            $elem.text(output);



          if(doneChars === totalChars){
                clearInterval(timer);
          }

          doneChars++;
        }, INTERVAL);

    }

  $('#change').click(function(){

    newOutput($output, $('#text').val());

  });
});
```

Comment: Let `totalTimePerCharacter = totalTimeToGenerateString / numOfCharactersInString`. Assuming you have a constant amount of time between character changes, `numOfCharacterChanges = totalTimePerCharacter / timeBetweenCharacters`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by setting the total amount of time you want to perform the mutation then dividing that amount of time by the length of the target string. That will give you the amount of time to spend on each character. From there, you can use a set amount of time between mutations and have it continuously mutate the last character before inserting the correct one.

```js
$(function(){
  var chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ'.split('');
  function getRandomInt(min, max){
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1)) + min;
  }

  function randomChar(){
    return chars[getRandomInt(0, chars.length - 1)];
  }
  
  var $output = $('#output');
  $output.text($output.text() + ' be');

  var INTERVAL = 50;
  var TOTAL_TIME = 2000;
  var TIME_PER_SWAP = 50;
  var newOutput = function($elem, $newText) {
    var chars = $newText.split('');
    var totalChars = chars.length;
    var doneChars = 0;
    // Total amount of time to spend on each new character
    var timePerCharacter = TOTAL_TIME / totalChars;
    setTimeout(function changeChar() {
      $elem.text($elem.text().slice(0, doneChars) + chars[doneChars++]);
      if (doneChars < totalChars) {
        setTimeout(changeChar, timePerCharacter);
      }
    }, timePerCharacter)
    
    // Randomly mix up the character
    setTimeout(function mix() {
      if (doneChars >= totalChars) {
       return;
      }
      $elem.text($elem.text().slice(0, doneChars) + randomChar());
      setTimeout(mix, TIME_PER_SWAP);
    }, 0);
  }
  
  $('#change').click(function(){
    newOutput($output, $('#text').val());
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" id="text" />
<input type="button" id="change" value="Change" />
<br /><br />
<span id="output">This is where the output will</span>
```

Comment: Thank you, this is perfect!

Answer (score 1):

Here's my reference implementation, not using jQuery, just good old vanillaJS  :)

```js
var chars = '0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
var els = document.querySelectorAll('div'), d;

function randChar() {
  return chars[Math.floor(Math.random() * chars.length)];
}
function setCharAt(str,index,chr) {
  if(index > str.length-1) return str;
  return str.substr(0,index) + chr + str.substr(index+1);
}
function unwind(el, arr, interval)
{
  el.innerText = arr.pop();
  if(arr.length)
    setTimeout(function(){unwind(el, arr, interval)}, interval);
}
for(var i = 0; i != els.length; i++)
{
  d = els[i];
  var origText = d.innerText, twists = [d.innerText];
  var iterations = Math.round(Math.sqrt(origText.length) * 10);
  var timePer = Math.round(2000 / iterations);
  while(--iterations)
  {
    origText = setCharAt(origText, Math.floor(Math.random() * origText.length), randChar());
    twists.push(origText);
  }
  unwind(d, twists, timePer);
}
```

```css
div {
  margin:1em;
  border:1px solid black;
  font:9pt monospace;
  padding:0.25em;
}
```

```html
<div>Test1</div>
<div>ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet</div>
<div>Quis non odit sordidos, vanos, leves, futtiles? Aliter homines, aliter philosophos loqui putas oportere? Semovenda est igitur voluptas, non solum ut recta sequamini, sed etiam ut loqui deceat frugaliter. Unum nescio, quo modo possit, si luxuriosus sit, finitas cupiditates habere. Si est nihil nisi corpus, summa erunt illa: valitudo, vacuitas doloris, pulchritudo, cetera. Primum quid tu dicis breve?</div>
<div>What is this 'Lorem Ipsum' or 'Lorum Ipsum' stuff?

In publishing and graphic design, placeholder text is commonly used to demonstrate the elements of a document or visual presentation, such as font, typography, and layout. Even though using "lorem ipsum" often arouses curiosity because of its resemblance to classical Latin, it is not intended to have meaning. Where text is visible in a document, people tend to focus on the textual content rather than upon overall presentation, so publishers use lorem ipsum when displaying a typeface or design elements and page layout in order to direct the focus to the publication style and not the meaning of the text. 
</div>
```

Comment: Ooh, I like this effect quite a lot!